# A probability inequality of events

Tags: probability, inequality

$A_i$ is events, $P(A_i)$ is not all zeors, $i=1,\cdots,n$.  Proof:
$$
P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right) \ge \frac{\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n P(A_i) \right)^2 }{ 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P(A_i) + 2\sum\limits_{i<j} P(A_i A_j) }
$$

The problem is from our final exam which I did not solve it.

I tried general addition formula, that is
$$
P(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i ) = \sum P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j} P(A_iA_j) + \cdots + (-1)^n P(A_1A_2\cdots A_n)
$$

then I write the inequalty as
$$
\left(\sum P(A_i) - \sum_{i<j} P(A_iA_j) + \cdots + (-1)^n P(A_1A_2\cdots A_n) \right) \left( { 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P(A_i) + 2\sum\limits_{i<j} P(A_i A_j) } \right)
\ge \left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n P(A_i) \right)^2
$$

I don't know what should I do to proof the above.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Consider the case of two events $A$ and $B$ where at least one of them occur with positive probability.

By Cauchy-Schwarz, for random variables $X$ and $Y$,

$$E\left[X^2\right]E\left[Y^2\right]\ge \left(E\left[XY\right]\right)^2\,,$$

whenever the expectations exist.

Take $X=I_{A\cup B}$ and $Y=I_A+I_B$, where $I_A$ is the indicator of event $A$.

Then

\begin{align}
E\left[X^2\right]E\left[Y^2\right]&=E\left[I^2_{A\cup B}\right]E\left[(I_A+I_B)^2\right]
\\&=E\left[I_{A\cup B}\right]E\left[I_A^2+I_B^2+2I_{A}I_{B}\right]
\\&=E\left[I_{A\cup B}\right]E\left[I_A+I_B+2I_{A\cap B}\right]
\\&=P(A\cup B)\left\{P(A)+P(B)+2P(A\cap B)\right\}
\end{align}

And

\begin{align}
E\left[XY\right]&=E\left[I_{A\cup B}(I_{A}+I_B)\right]
\\&=E\left[(I_A+I_B-I_{A\cap B})(I_{A}+I_B)\right]
\\&=E\left[(I_A+I_B)^2-I_{(A\cap B) \cap A}-I_{(A\cap B)\cap B}\right]
\\&=E\left[I_{A}+I_B+2I_{A\cap B}-I_{A\cap B}-I_{A\cap B}\right]
\\&=E\left[I_{A}+I_B\right]
\\&=P(A)+P(B)
\end{align}

Comment: An excellent answer, thank you.